# Pull object from an array with node-mongodb-native

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm struggling with a simple operation with the mongodb native driver for nodejs.
Here is my mongo document:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "foo" : "bar",
    "baz" : [
         {
            "a" : "b",
            "c" : 1
         },
         {
            "a" : "b",
            "c" : 2
         }
    ]
}
```

and I have a var like the following :

```
var removeIt = {"a" : "b", "c" : 1};
```

So to pull this object from the `baz` array I try to do the following :

```
collection.update(
        {_id:1}, 
        {$pull:{baz:{a:removeIt.a, c:removeIt.c}}},
        {safe:true},
        function(err, result) {}
);
```

But this doesn't seem to work, and I cannot get why, any idea?

Comment: I would think you would need to use: {$pull:{baz:{ removeIt }}}, instead - did you try that?

Comment: Thans for your comment, but this throws an error, and ```{$pull:{baz: removeIt }}``` just do nothing like my implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried this on the MongoShell, and the following works for me:

```
> db.test.insert( {
    "_id" : 1,
    "foo" : "bar",
    "baz" : [
         {
            "a" : "b",
            "c" : 1
         },
         {
            "a" : "b",
            "c" : 2
         }
    ]
});

> db.test.findOne();
{ "_id" : 1, "baz" : [ { "a" : "b", "c": 1 }, { "a" : "b", "c" : 2 } ], "foo" : "bar" }

> removeIt = {"a" : "b", "c" : 1};
> db.test.update( { _id: 1 }, { $pull: { baz: removeIt } } );

> db.test.findOne();
{ "_id" : 1, "baz" : [ { "a" : "b", "c" : 2 } ], "foo" : "bar" }
```

So modify your:

```
{$pull:{baz:{a:removeIt.a, c:removeIt.c}}}
```

to:

```
{$pull:{baz: removeIt}}
```

And it should work.

Comment: Yes, it also works for me from the mongo shell, but not with the node-mongodb-native driver